# Google Sheets QUERY FORMULA TRANSPOSE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

With the formula "QUERY", I want to convert the data in the "IN" table to the "OUT" table. How should I create the "QUERY" formula?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=transpose(flatten(query(A2:B4)))
```

[image]

But this can also be done without query.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(A2:B4))
```

[image]

### Reference:

- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en)